# How to update a set of data with reverse scoring on SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a set of data with collected as 1-4 but I have to convert the scoring in order to count the component scores.

By converting the scoring I meant as follow:
If the score is '1' - I need to convert into '4'
'2' convert to '3'
'3' convert to '2'
'4' convert to '1'

I have tried to used the update query but it kind of screwed it up as when something converted into '1' from '4', they will eventually be converted into '1' at the end of the query.

Sample Code:

```
Update BIS5 Set bis_bar_7 = 4 where bis_bar_7 = 1;
Update BIS5 Set bis_bar_7 = 3 where bis_bar_7 = 2;
Update BIS5 Set bis_bar_7 = 2 where bis_bar_7 = 3;
Update BIS5 Set bis_bar_7 = 1 where bis_bar_7 = 4;
```

So after I run this- Update BIS5 Set bis_bar_7 = 4 where bis_bar_7 = 1;
there will have more data with '4' and will then be converted when I run this line - Update BIS5 Set bis_bar_7 = 1 where bis_bar_7 = 4;

So What I should do without messing other data and just correcting the original data?

Any suggestion of where I should run it too? The file I have is on CSV and I then converted into SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You may update using a single `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE BIS5
SET bis_bar_7 = CASE bis_bar_7 WHEN 4 THEN 1
                               WHEN 3 THEN 2
                               WHEN 2 THEN 3
                               WHEN 1 THEN 4 END
WHERE
    bis_bar_7 IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for the help. Do you think I can do that in Python with Panda? Since I have my file in CSV.

Comment: Pandas is a totally different language/framework than SQLite.  You asked a SQL question, which has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `CASE`:

```
UPDATE BIS5 
SET bis_bar_7 = 5 - bis_bar_7 
WHERE bis_bar_7 IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

By subtracting the current value of `bis_bar_7` from 5 you get the value that you want to be saved.